# Vba add border to row if date changes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large spreadsheet with up to 20 columns. The date is in column C. What I'd like to do is have a macro that adds a border to the last row of a date in order to separate rows into dates. Ie

```
2/2/15
2/2/15
2/2/15
______
3/2/15
3/2/15
```

I would also like the border to extend the width of the sheet. Also it may be important to note there may be larger gaps between dates than just the next day.

Comment: So you want to cycle through column C and add a bottom border for every last instance of a particular date and have this border extend from column 1 to column 20? What have you tried?

Comment: Sub AddB()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Range("C" & i).Value <> Range("C" & i - 1).Value Then
        Range("C" & i - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30914712/edit) your question to include your code.

Comment: Just pointing out that you can do it with conditional formatting as well (without VBA). Assuming the dates are in column A, select the whole sheet, and enter =$A1<>$A2 as the formula for conditional formatting, and set the format to add a bottom border

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional formatting, you can easily do this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This macro code:

```
For i = 2 To UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Loop through all used cells
    If Cells(i - 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then 'If cell differs from previous cell
        Cells(i - 1, 1).Select 'Select it
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom) 'change the border
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

Produced this output:

[image: output]

As your dates are in Column C you will need to change all instances of

```
Cells(i, 1) and Cells(i - 1, 1)
```

with

```
Cells(i, 3) or Cells(i - 1, 3)
```

Comment: I need it as a vba ray. Wightboy, I'm getting a run time error 424: object required

Comment: Hi Dan, are you copying the code into a macro sub-routine? If so can you change "UsedRange.Rows.Count" to the number of rows there are and see if that works please?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while researching the very issue the original poster asked. The code provide by Wrightboy works if you change UsedRange.Rows.Count to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count.

I realize I am posting on something that is several years old, but wanted to add this information incase someone like me stumbled upon it in down the road.